# Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe Iterations

Tags: code-golf, math, pi

## Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe Iterations

We've seen a few pi challenges on PPCG, but none that specifically dictate the algorithm you should be using. I'd like to see implementations of the [Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) in any language up to iteration `n`. The formula is as follows:

[image: Modified formula.]

Your algorithm should output each iteration up to n, showing intermediate sums as well as the final result to form a "piangle". You may also use the reduced polynomial form of the algorithm shown on the wikipedia page. An example run for `n=50` is shown below:

```
3
3.1
3.14
3.141
3.1415
3.14159
3.141592
3.1415926
3.14159265
3.141592653
3.1415926535
3.14159265358
3.141592653589
3.1415926535897
3.14159265358979
3.141592653589793
3.1415926535897932
3.14159265358979323
3.141592653589793238
3.1415926535897932384
3.14159265358979323846
3.141592653589793238462
3.1415926535897932384626
3.14159265358979323846264
3.141592653589793238462643
3.1415926535897932384626433
3.14159265358979323846264338
3.141592653589793238462643383
3.1415926535897932384626433832
3.14159265358979323846264338327
3.141592653589793238462643383279
3.1415926535897932384626433832795
3.14159265358979323846264338327950
3.141592653589793238462643383279502
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
```

The precision of each iteration should equal the `n` that is passed to the algorithm, that is to say that each iteration should calculate pi up to the passed `n` for all `k`.

## Rules:

- Built-ins are not allowed, nor is `pi`, you must use the formula.
- You must support `n` up to a maximum that your language allows in terms of the calculation of `16^n`. If the input is causing an arithmetic overflow during calculation after `x<n` executions because your language only supports decimals up to `2^32-1`, this is fine. Any other assumptions on `n` are not fine.
- You **MUST** provide an explanation of how you got the output if it is not obvious. For instance, if you're posting in a Golfing language a break-down is 100% required. This is to ensure you're using the algorithm that is specified.
- Standard loop-holes are disallowed.
- This is code-golf, lowest byte count wins here.

Reference Code (Code used to Generate Example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    (0..50).each {
        n->
        def x=(0..n).collect {
            j->
            def k=new BigDecimal(j)
            def s={it.setScale(n)}
            def a=s(1.0g).divide(s(16.0g)**s(k))
            def b=s(4.0g)/(s(8.0g)*s(k)+s(1.0g))
            def c=s(2.0g)/(s(8.0g)*s(k)+s(4.0g))
            def d=s(1.0g)/(s(8.0g)*s(k)+s(5.0g))
            def e=s(1.0g)/(s(8.0g)*s(k)+s(6.0g))
            def f=a*(b-c-d-e)
        }.sum()
        println(n + "\t" + x.setScale(n, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN))
    }
}
```

This implementation caps out at `n=255`, you may cap out at less or more.
This implementation was done in Groovy.

Comment: The only downside I see is that it will be difficult to verify exactly what method someone is using soley based on the output, which is generally a problem with `Calculate foo via x method` challenges.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Added an explanation of the code you post being required if it is not an obvious implementation, to ensure we can actually tell what they did. The algorithm is actually fairly straightforward though, so it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: @Emigna it should correctly calculate pi to `k` digits on each iteration using the algorithm provided. So the precision is important.

Comment: With respect to @DJMcMayhem's comment, see the advice to [avoid non-observable program requirements](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10002/194).

Comment: @carusocomputing: What I meant was, is it okay to output more than n digits, where the digits after the nth may or may not be correct or if the result should be exactly n digits, but I removed the comment as it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Emigna the overall goal was to match the output provided using the algorithm specified for all `n`, probably would've been better to not use the rounding at all; as that would've made it more observable, but it's a bit late now.

Comment: *You must support n up to a maximum that your language allows.* Allows how? Can I use recursion? Can I use lists if generators would be more memory-friendly? Can I use 2n digits and chop the last n off?

Comment: In the interest of clarity, I'd just remove the ordinals before that output that is actually required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>63</s> <s>52</s> 50 bytes

**Specialization formula**

```
Îƒ0NU62201122vyÍ¹Ì°*8X*N>+÷+}16Xm÷+DX>£X__iÀ'.ìÁ},
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w47GkjBOVTYyMjAxMTIydnnDjcK5w4zCsCo4WCpOPivDtyt9MTZYbcO3K0RYPsKjWF9facOAJy7DrMOBfSw&input=MTAw)

**BBP formula**

```
ƒ4¹>°UX*8N*©>÷YX*®4+÷-1X*®5+÷-1X*®6+÷-1X*16Nm÷*ODN>£N__iÀ'.ìÁ},
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xpI0wrk-wrBVWCo4TirCqT7Dt1lYKsKuNCvDty0xWCrCrjUrw7ctMVgqwq42K8O3LTFYKjE2Tm3DtypPRE4-wqNOX19pw4AnLsOsw4F9LA&input=MTAw)

Comment: "Your algorithm should output each iteration up to n, showing intermediate sums as well as the final result to form a "piangle".", basically just perform this from 0 to n, pushing each to the stack and it'll be good.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Maybe change the wording on *Outputting the current iteration's n is optional* as I understood that as only the final result is necessary.

Comment: Or maybe it's just me that's bad at reading (I know I tend to skip parts when I feel that I have the gist)

Comment: Maybe just *us*, but definitely not just *you*.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Iterations added. Need to find a cheaper way to do it as the "." was very expensive.

Comment: Could you suggest an edit for the wording? I'm not sure how else to word it. I meant literally outputting the `n`.

Comment: @carusocomputing Something like *in addition to printing the k digits calculated at each step of the algorithm, you may also output the current iteration number*. Although I can't see why that bit is there at all as it's very unlikely that doing so will save bytes.

Comment: I think the original wording is just fine. "Outputting the current iteration's n is optional." `n` *is* the iteration number, not the intermediate sum.

Comment: so uh separate question: is there a reason to use every character in unicode set but english alphabets

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Not exactly sure what you're asking. There are only a few characters in this answer that aren't numbers or in the latin alphabet and I think I needed them. This answer could be made shorter today though.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>109</s> 108 bytes

```python
def f(n):k=1;s=0;t=100**n;exec-~n*'s+=4*t/k-2*t/(k+3)-t/(k+4)-t/(k+5)>>k/2;print"3."[:k]+`s`[1:k/8+1];k+=8;'
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/H61RgM).

Answer (score 4):

## PARI/GP, 86 bytes

```
n->for(k=p=0,n,printf("%."k"f\n",(p=16*p-4/(3-j=8*k+4)-2/j-1/j++-1/j++)\(8/5)^k/10^k))
```

Or without the decimal point in **69 bytes**:

```
n->for(k=p=0,n,print((p=16*p-4/(3-j=8*k+4)-2/j-1/j++-1/j++)\(8/5)^k))
```

Rather than dividing through by *16<sup>k</sup>* each iteration, the previous value of *p* is instead multiplied by *16*. Floor of *p ÷ (8/5)<sup>k</sup>* is then the value of *π* truncated to the correct number of digits.

**Sample Usage**

```
$ gp
? n->for(k=p=0,n,printf("%."k"f\n",(p=16*p-4/(3-j=8*k+4)-2/j-1/j++-1/j++)\(8/5)^k/10^k))
? %(20)
3
3.1
3.14
3.141
3.1415
3.14159
3.141592
3.1415926
3.14159265
3.141592653
3.1415926535
3.14159265358
3.141592653589
3.1415926535897
3.14159265358979
3.141592653589793
3.1415926535897932
3.14159265358979323
3.141592653589793238
3.1415926535897932384
3.14159265358979323846
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 174 Bytes

Man, this is a time when I wish that Python had some easier way of keeping infinite precision for decimals.. Possibly implementing your own infite accuracy type for this challenge is shorter but I can't imagine how. The formula is written verbatim.

```python
from decimal import*
n=input();d=Decimal;getcontext().prec=n+2;p=d(0)
for i in range(n+1):f=8.*i;p+=d(16**(-i))*(4/d(f+1)-2/d(f+4)-1/d(f+5)-1/d(f+6));print str(p)[:-~i+(i>0)]
```

Example output for `n=100` (with some added line numbers):

```
3
3.1
3.14
3.141
3.1415
3.14159
3.141592
3.1415926
3.14159265
3.141592653
3.1415926535
3.14159265358
3.141592653589
3.1415926535897
3.14159265358979
3.141592653589793
3.1415926535897932
3.14159265358979323
3.141592653589793238
3.1415926535897932384
3.14159265358979323846
3.141592653589793238462
3.1415926535897932384626
3.14159265358979323846264
3.141592653589793238462643
3.1415926535897932384626433
3.14159265358979323846264338
3.141592653589793238462643383
3.1415926535897932384626433832
3.14159265358979323846264338327
3.141592653589793238462643383279
3.1415926535897932384626433832795
3.14159265358979323846264338327950
3.141592653589793238462643383279502
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
```

This does seem to work for larger numbers, `n=1000` runs in a couple seconds and `n=10000` doesn't seem to have given me any errors yet!

Answer (score 3):

## J, <s>73</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```
(j.":"+10&^(<.@*%[)[:+/\16&^%~[:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8)@i.@>:
```

This outputs each approximation to *n* digits as a formatted string. This uses the polynomial simplification of the formula and gets the first *n* digits by multiplying the sum by a power of 10, flooring it, and dividing by that same power of 10.

The input is taken as an extended integer, meaning that rationals are used when division occurs which keeps results exact.

### Usage

This is the output for *n* = 100, showing the cumulative sums for *k* in [0, 100].

```
   f =: (j.":"+10&^(<.@*%[)[:+/\16&^%~[:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8)@i.@>:
   f 100x
3                                                                                                     
3.1                                                                                                   
3.14                                                                                                  
3.141                                                                                                 
3.1415                                                                                                
3.14159                                                                                               
3.141592                                                                                              
3.1415926                                                                                             
3.14159265                                                                                            
3.141592653                                                                                           
3.1415926535                                                                                          
3.14159265358                                                                                         
3.141592653589                                                                                        
3.1415926535897                                                                                       
3.14159265358979                                                                                      
3.141592653589793                                                                                     
3.1415926535897932                                                                                    
3.14159265358979323                                                                                   
3.141592653589793238                                                                                  
3.1415926535897932384                                                                                 
3.14159265358979323846                                                                                
3.141592653589793238462                                                                               
3.1415926535897932384626                                                                              
3.14159265358979323846264                                                                             
3.141592653589793238462643                                                                            
3.1415926535897932384626433                                                                           
3.14159265358979323846264338                                                                          
3.141592653589793238462643383                                                                         
3.1415926535897932384626433832                                                                        
3.14159265358979323846264338327                                                                       
3.141592653589793238462643383279                                                                      
3.1415926535897932384626433832795                                                                     
3.14159265358979323846264338327950                                                                    
3.141592653589793238462643383279502                                                                   
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028                                                                  
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288                                                                 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884                                                                
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841                                                               
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419                                                              
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197                                                             
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971                                                            
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716                                                           
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169                                                          
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693                                                         
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939                                                        
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399                                                       
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993                                                      
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937                                                     
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375                                                    
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751                                                   
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510                                                  
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105                                                 
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058                                                
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582                                               
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820                                              
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209                                             
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097                                            
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974                                           
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749                                          
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494                                         
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944                                        
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445                                       
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459                                      
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592                                     
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923                                    
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230                                   
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307                                  
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078                                 
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781                                
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816                               
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164                              
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640                             
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406                            
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062                           
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628                          
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286                         
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862                        
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620                       
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208                      
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089                     
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899                    
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998                   
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986                  
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862                 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628                
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280               
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803              
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034             
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348            
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482           
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825          
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253         
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534        
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342       
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421      
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211     
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117    
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170   
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706  
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067 
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679
```

### Explanation

First make the range [0, *n*], shown for *n* = 5

```
   i. >: 5
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Multiply each by 8

```
   (*&8) i. >: 5
0 8 16 24 32 40
```

Form the addition table between `[1, 4, 5, 6]` and the products with 8

```
   (1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
1  9 17 25 33 41
4 12 20 28 36 44
5 13 21 29 37 45
6 14 22 30 38 46
```

Divide each row by `[4, 2, -1, 1]`

```
   (4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
       4   0.444444  0.235294       0.16  0.121212   0.097561
     0.5   0.166667       0.1  0.0714286 0.0555556  0.0454545
    _0.2 _0.0769231 _0.047619 _0.0344828 _0.027027 _0.0222222
0.166667  0.0714286 0.0454545  0.0333333 0.0263158  0.0217391
```

Then reduce the columns from bottom-to-top using subtraction

```
   ([:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
3.13333 0.129426 0.0422205 0.0207553 0.0123137 0.00814508
```

Divide each 16<sup>*k*</sup> for *k* in [0, *n*] by each result

```
   (16&^%~[:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
3.13333 0.00808913 0.000164924 5.06722e_6 1.87893e_7 7.76775e_9
```

Find the cumulative sums

```
   ([:+/\16&^%~[:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
3.13333 3.14142 3.14159 3.14159 3.14159 3.14159
```

Compute 10<sup>*k*</sup> for *k* in [0, *n*] and multiply it with each

```
   (10&^(*)[:+/\16&^%~[:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
3.13333 31.4142 314.159 3141.59 31415.9 314159
```

Then floor each of the products

```
   (10&^(<.@*)[:+/\16&^%~[:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
3 31 314 3141 31415 314159
```

Divide it by the same power of 10 to get the results

```
   (10&^(<.@*%[)[:+/\16&^%~[:-/4 2 _1 1%1 4 5 6+/*&8) i. >: 5
3 3.1 3.14 3.141 3.1415 3.14159
```

Comment: Nicee! Glad someone used the polynomial simplification.

Comment: @carusocomputing Unfortunately I just got it shorter using the coefficients by building a table of values to sum column-wise

Comment: Still, nicely done on both implementations.

Answer (score 3):

## C GCC, 118 bytes

Golfed:

```
main(){double k,a,s=1,t;k=a=0;while(k<15){t=k++*8;a+=(4/(t+1)-2/(t+4)-1/(t+5)-1/(t+6))/s;s*=16;printf("%.15lf\n",a);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
main(){
    double k,a,s=1,t;
    k=a=0;
    while(k<15){
        t=k++*8;
        a+=(4/(t+1)-2/(t+4)-1/(t+5)-1/(t+6))/s;
        s*=16;
        printf("%.15lf\n",a);
    }
}
```

To change n, just change while(k<15) to while(k < n)

output:

```
$ gcc pigolf.c -o pigolf
some gcc screaming warnings
$ ./pigolf 
3.133333333333333
3.141422466422466
3.141587390346582
3.141592457567436
3.141592645460336
3.141592653228088
3.141592653572881
3.141592653588973
3.141592653589752
3.141592653589791
3.141592653589793
3.141592653589793
3.141592653589793
3.141592653589793
3.141592653589793
```

max precision is 15 decimal places, i could increase to any value with gmp, but maybe next pi day :P

### with pretty print, 143 bytes

Golfed:

```
main(){double k,a,s=1,t;char o[19];k=a=0;while(k<15){t=k++*8;a+=(4/(t+1)-2/(t+4)-1/(t+5)-1/(t+6))/s;s*=16;snprintf(o,k+3,"%.15lf",a);puts(o);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
main(){
    double k,a,s=1,t;
    char o[19];
    k=a=0;
    while(k<15){
        t=k++*8;
        a+=(4/(t+1)-2/(t+4)-1/(t+5)-1/(t+6))/s;
        s*=16;
        snprintf(o,k+3,"%.15lf",a);
        puts(o);
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ gcc pigolf_pretty.c -o pigolf_pretty
more gcc screaming warnings
$ ./pigolf_pretty
3.1
3.14
3.141
3.1415
3.14159
3.141592
3.1415926
3.14159265
3.141592653
3.1415926535
3.14159265358
3.141592653589
3.1415926535897
3.14159265358979
3.141592653589793
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a nice first answer :)

Comment: Parenthesis near the - would be not necessary

Comment: Thank you @RosLuP :)

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcTBCsIwDADQX5GBkCypJbqJUPsnXmq1Mjo7WeNJ/PZ68R1eNI8YW7st7@t832QOXL2wumeYCuAnLSu4fJbR1d7LEdVnov5EA7/WqWiCbruTcU6X0nEgD4MFNQc0e6tGLNF/tBXdt7Uf "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat ++t many times inside one statement would be for C (and C compiler) Undefined Behaviour

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>101</s> 100 bytes

Thanks to @nimi for a byte.

```
f n=take(n+2).show$sum[1/16^k*(4/(l+1)-2/(l+4)-1/(l+5)-1/(l+6))|k<-[0..100+n],l<-[8*fromIntegral k]]
```

Straightforward implementation. Calculates `n` up to 15 digits (standard double precision).

Comment: `l<-[8*fromIntegral k]` instead of the `let ...` saves a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 125 bytes

```
p:=0;@For(n:=0;n<=a;n:=n+1;b:=8*n;p:=p+@Power(16;-n)*(4/(b+1)-2/(b+4)-1/(b+5)-1/(b+6));o:=o:@Left(@Text(p);n+@If(n=0;1;2)));o
```

Formula in a computed field with another field called "a" for input.

Basically a port of the algorithm from the Python answer from @shebang. Calculates up to 15 digits after which it truncates due to a limitation of the language (see output). Had to waste 12 bytes with the @If statement at the end just to get rid of the . after the 3 at the start :-/

[image: Sample Output]

**Ungolfed**

```
p:=0;
@For(n:=0; n<=a; n:=n+1;
 b:=8*n;
 p:=p+@Power(16;-n)*(4/(b+1)-2/(b+4)-1/(b+5)-1/(b+6));
 o:=o:@Left(@Text(p);n+@If(n=0;1;2))
 );
o
```

Comment: but then Notes formula is never going going to be a golfing language. Thanks to @Shebang for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 183 bytes

Golfed:

```
void F(int n){double s=0;for(int k=0;k<=n;k++){s+=1/Math.Pow(16,k)*(4.0/(8*k+1)-2.0/(8*k+4)-1.0/(8*k+5)-1.0/(8*k+6));double p=Math.Pow(10,k);Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(s*p)/p);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
void F(int n)
{
    double s = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
    {
        s += 1/Math.Pow(16, k)*(4.0/(8*k + 1) - 2.0/(8*k + 4) - 1.0/(8*k + 5) - 1.0/(8*k + 6));
        double p = Math.Pow(10, k);

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(s*p)/p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this print `3.14159265358979` for any `n >= 14` due to double precision?

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea for workaround.

Comment: You can use the BigInteger library when calculating and then formatting the output as a string.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 206 chars, 412 bytes

```
fdn←{1∧÷⍵}⋄fnm←{1∧⍵}⋄r2fs←{q←⌈-/10x⍟¨(fdn ⍵),fnm ⍵⋄m←⎕ct⋄⎕ct←0⋄a←⌊⍵×10x*⍺⋄⎕ct←m⋄k←≢b←⍕a⋄0≥k-⍺:'0.',((⍺-k)⍴'0'),b⋄((k-⍺)↑b),'.',(k-⍺)↓b}⋄p←{+/¨{k←1+8×⍵⋄(+/4 2 1 1÷k,-k+3..5)÷16*⍵}¨¨{0..⍵}¨0..⍵}⋄q←{⍪⍵r2fs¨p⍵}
```

This find all approssimation in big rational, than use one function that convert big rational in numeric string... test:

```
 q 1x
3.1 
3.1 
  q 2x
3.13 
3.14 
3.14 
  q 3x
3.133 
3.141 
3.141 
3.141 
  q 10x
3.1333333333 
3.1414224664 
3.1415873903 
3.1415924575 
3.1415926454 
3.1415926532 
3.1415926535 
3.1415926535 
3.1415926535 
3.1415926535 
3.1415926535 
  q 20x
3.13333333333333333333 
3.14142246642246642246 
3.14158739034658152305 
3.14159245756743538183 
3.14159264546033631955 
3.14159265322808753473 
3.14159265357288082778 
3.14159265358897270494 
3.14159265358975227523 
3.14159265358979114638 
3.14159265358979312961 
3.14159265358979323271 
3.14159265358979323815 
3.14159265358979323844 
3.14159265358979323846 
3.14159265358979323846 
3.14159265358979323846 
3.14159265358979323846 
3.14159265358979323846 
3.14159265358979323846 
3.14159265358979323846 
  q 57x     
3.133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 
3.141422466422466422466422466422466422466422466422466422466 
3.141587390346581523052111287405405052463875993287757993640 
3.141592457567435381837004555057293394007389950594818748976 
3.141592645460336319557021222442381831727406617979907186696 
3.141592653228087534734378035536204469558528012197801934814 
3.141592653572880827785240761895898484239065603786606461624 
3.141592653588972704940777767170189446971120489811822860633 
3.141592653589752275236177868398102225795024633409061087027 
3.141592653589791146388776965910347414779015888488996772587 
3.141592653589793129614170564041344858816452676296281615895 
3.141592653589793232711292261930077163422606275435901151635 
3.141592653589793238154766322501863827762609260414389714560 
3.141592653589793238445977501940281666096938425156252904675 
3.141592653589793238461732482037982486800056278143046732780 
3.141592653589793238462593174670682882792683045699610435502 
3.141592653589793238462640595138128445061235672871301070791 
3.141592653589793238462643227424822458237094279625505676929 
3.141592653589793238462643374515761485970237552267559842751 
3.141592653589793238462643382784091514246623611329334708720 
3.141592653589793238462643383251362615881909316518417908555 
3.141592653589793238462643383277897474896408560218644955706 
3.141592653589793238462643383279410929692483875831459799593 
3.141592653589793238462643383279497597978087353533999465917 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502579284902684600486947911 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502866555094658758532859204 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502883173477103651067488504 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884137610730938143080855 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884193695667358321264063 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884196966326705909950134 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197157502154596455091 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197168700950456888403 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169358296080453391 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169396954642664355 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399232246022950 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399366660542801 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399374605817825 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375076175949 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375104060947 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105716347 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105814747 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820603 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820952 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820973 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974 
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974
```